# PHP upload temporary file not available outside of PHP context

Tags: php

I've got the upload script which accepts the file and process it further.
Before file is processed its temporary upload path is given to `clamav` which will read the file outside of the PHP context and return whether there is virus inside or not.

This workflow has worked quite well until it stopped. I've debugged my script and even though file gets processed correctly on the PHP side, it doesn't exist in the tmp location given in `$_FILES` (during the script execution before script finishes).

```
$_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'];
# This gives the location: /tmp/phpxbXzY0 correctly.

file_get_contents($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name']); 
# This returns the file content correctly.
```

However when I am logged in as `sudo` on the machine and type: `cat /tmp/phpxbXzY0` there is no such file.

What's weird that it happened on all my PHP servers, but on local it all works fine and I can read the file contents with `cat` command.

I am running `7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` on Ubuntu 18.04 on EC2, kernel: `4.15.0-1009-aws`

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: What's your local version of PHP?

Comment: It's all the same environment. On local it's running as Ubuntu 18.04 Docker container.

Comment: what about lifetime of temporary file ? when file is moved or script execution ends temp file should be deleted, maybe that does not happen on your local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason on my servers configuration of: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service` file was the default one.

By default it has: `PrivateTmp=true` while it should've been: `PrivateTmp=false`

That's the feature of `systemd`: https://serverfault.com/questions/786211/access-files-in-system-tmp-directory-when-using-privatetmp

The problem wasn't present on my local, since `Apache2` isn't started by `systemd` therefore not restricting the `/tmp` path.

I need to check now why the file version has changed, since it was working fine enough. I suspect there must be unattended upgrade enabled, since I am not sure what else could cause it.